# Fullcalendar, how to call month method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar.

And i want to change my calendar, so the default month is June (the initial month for loading), I believe this is what I need:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/month/

The problem is, I'm not very good at .js... and the explanation isn't very clear.

This is what i tried:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoMonth', 7);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: [
                    {
                    imageAfterTime: $("<img src = 'images/flags/za.png' style='width:19px;height:13px'/>"),
                    imageAfterTitle: $("<img src = 'images/flags/mx.png' style='width:19px;height:13px'/>"),
                    title:' RSA-MEX ',
                    start:   '2010-06-11T14:30:00',
                    allDay: false,
                    },
>>>rest of events...
```

You can see my calendar at:
http://cudamine.com/icame/sitemundial/calendar.html

Can anyone help me out calling this month method?

Answer (score 3):

> "I want to change my calendar, so the default month is June."

The question is a little unclear.  Your calendar **is** starting at June per the `month: 5,` parameter in the calendar initialization.

BUT the code snippet, above, appears to be trying to go to August (month 7).   So what is really wanted?

`gotoMonth` also appears to be obsolete; it's not in the official documentation (¿anymore?).

You would use the  [**gotoDate**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)  function and you would place it after the calendar initialization.  Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var CurrentDate = new Date();
    var CurrentYear = CurrentDate.getFullYear();

    var MyCalendar  = $('#calendar');
    MyCalendar.fullCalendar(
    {
        defaultView: 'month',
        month: 5,
        editable: true,
        events: [
                {
                    imageAfterTime: $("<img src = 'images/flags/za.png' style='width:19px;height:13px'/>"),
                    imageAfterTitle: $("<img src = 'images/flags/mx.png' style='width:19px;height:13px'/>"),
                    title: ' RSA-MEX ',
                    start: '2010-06-11T14:30:00',
                    allDay: false,
                }
                //... More events ... ...
                ],
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        eventRender: function (event, eventElement)
        {
            if (event.imageAfterTime)
                eventElement.find('span.fc-event-time').after($(event.imageAfterTime));

            if (event.imageAfterTitle)
                eventElement.find('span.fc-event-title').after($(event.imageAfterTitle));
        }
    });

    //-- Advance to the calendar to August (month 7).
    MyCalendar.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', CurrentYear, 7);
});
```